# how do I make a drop down menu show over scroll down page?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, scroll, menu

Sorry if this has been asked before, but I couldn't find an answer that worked.

The drop down menu in the navbar shows when the bar is ontop, but it doesn't when I scroll down the page.

How do I make the dropdown menu show above the text of the page when is scrolled?

here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {
margin: 0;
font-size: 28px;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.header {
background-color: #f1f1f1;
padding: 30px;
text-align: center;
}

#navbar {
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #333;
} 

#navbar a {
float: left;
display: block;
color: #f2f2f2;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 17px;
}

#navbar a:hover {
background-color: #ddd;
color: black; 
}

#navbar a.active {
background-color: red;
color: white;
}

.content {
padding: 16px;
}

.sticky {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
}

.sticky + .content {
padding-top: 60px;
}

/* The dropdown container */
.dropdown {
float: left;
overflow: hidden;
}

/* Dropdown button */
.dropdown .dropbtn {
font-size: 17px; 
border: none;
outline: none;
color: #f2f2f2;
padding: 14px 16px;
background-color: inherit;
font-family: inherit; /* Important for vertical align on mobile phones 
*/
margin: 0; /* Important for vertical align on mobile phones */
}

/* Add a red background color to navbar links on hover */
.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
background-color: #ddd;
color: black;
}

/* Dropdown content (hidden by default) */
.dropdown-content {
display: none;
position: absolute;
background-color: #f9f9f9;
min-width: 160px;
box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
z-index: 10;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
float: none;
color: black;
padding: 12px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
text-align: left;
}

/* Add a grey background color to dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {
background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
display: block;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="header">
<h2>Scroll Down</h2>
<p>Scroll down to see the sticky effect.</p>
</div>

<div id="navbar">
<a class="active" href="javascript:void(0)">Home</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)">News</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)">Contact</a>
<div class="dropdown">
<button class="dropbtn">Dropdown 
<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
</button>
<div class="dropdown-content">
<a href="#">Link 1</a>
<a href="#">Link 2</a>
<a href="#">Link 3</a>
</div>
</div> 
</div>

<div class="content">
<h3>Sticky Navigation Example</h3>
<p>The navbar will stick to the top when you reach its scroll 
position.</p>
<p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum 
definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas 
ut 
quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. 
Affert 
laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no 
molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
</div>

<script>
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
navbar.classList.add("sticky")
} else {
navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
}
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm a total beginner so thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
navbar.classList.add("sticky")
} else {
navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
}
}
```

```css
body {
margin: 0;
font-size: 28px;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.header {
background-color: #f1f1f1;
padding: 30px;
text-align: center;
}

#navbar {
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #333;
} 

#navbar a {
float: left;
display: block;
color: #f2f2f2;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 17px;
}

#navbar a:hover {
background-color: #ddd;
color: black; 
}

#navbar a.active {
background-color: red;
color: white;
}

.content {
padding: 16px;
}

.sticky {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
overflow: visible !important;
}

.sticky + .content {
padding-top: 60px;
}

/* The dropdown container */
.dropdown {
float: left;
overflow: hidden;
}

/* Dropdown button */
.dropdown .dropbtn {
font-size: 17px; 
border: none;
outline: none;
color: #f2f2f2;
padding: 14px 16px;
background-color: inherit;
font-family: inherit; /* Important for vertical align on mobile phones 
*/
margin: 0; /* Important for vertical align on mobile phones */
}

/* Add a red background color to navbar links on hover */
.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
background-color: #ddd;
color: black;
}

/* Dropdown content (hidden by default) */
.dropdown-content {
display: none;
position: absolute;
background-color: #f9f9f9;
min-width: 160px;
box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
z-index: 10;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
float: none;
color: black;
padding: 12px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
text-align: left;
}

/* Add a grey background color to dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {
background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
display: block;
}

.sticky .dropdown-content{
 top:48px;

  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>
<body>

<div class="header">
<h2>Scroll Down</h2>
<p>Scroll down to see the sticky effect.</p>
</div>

<div id="navbar">
<a class="active" href="javascript:void(0)">Home</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)">News</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)">Contact</a>
<div class="dropdown">
<button class="dropbtn">Dropdown 
<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
</button>
<div class="dropdown-content">
<a href="#">Link 1</a>
<a href="#">Link 2</a>
<a href="#">Link 3</a>
</div>
</div> 
</div>

<div class="content">
<h3>Sticky Navigation Example</h3>
<p>The navbar will stick to the top when you reach its scroll 
position.</p>
<p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum 
definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas 
ut 
quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. 
Affert 
laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no 
molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

you have to give 48px margin top or top to your dropdown because your navbar have 48px height thats why it is overlapping please check the code snippet i hope you got your answer

Answer (score 0):

It's because you added position:fixed; to navbar, dropdown-content has absolute position and it's overlapping. Your navbar height is 48px so add top:48px to dropdown-content when navbar is sticky and make navbar sticky overflow visible.

Updated Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {
margin: 0;
font-size: 28px;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.header {
background-color: #f1f1f1;
padding: 30px;
text-align: center;
}

#navbar {
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #333;
} 

#navbar a {
float: left;
display: block;
color: #f2f2f2;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 17px;
}

#navbar a:hover {
background-color: #ddd;
color: black; 
}

#navbar a.active {
background-color: red;
color: white;
}

.content {
padding: 16px;
}

.sticky {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
overflow: visible !important;
}

.sticky + .content {
padding-top: 60px;
}

/* The dropdown container */
.dropdown {
float: left;
overflow: hidden;
}

/* Dropdown button */
.dropdown .dropbtn {
font-size: 17px; 
border: none;
outline: none;
color: #f2f2f2;
padding: 14px 16px;
background-color: inherit;
font-family: inherit; /* Important for vertical align on mobile phones 
*/
margin: 0; /* Important for vertical align on mobile phones */
}

/* Add a red background color to navbar links on hover */
.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
background-color: #ddd;
color: black;
}

/* Dropdown content (hidden by default) */
.dropdown-content {
display: none;
position: absolute;
background-color: #f9f9f9;
min-width: 160px;
box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
z-index: 10;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
float: none;
color: black;
padding: 12px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
text-align: left;
}

/* Add a grey background color to dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {
background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
display: block;
}

.sticky .dropdown-content{
 top:48px;
  }

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="header">
<h2>Scroll Down</h2>
<p>Scroll down to see the sticky effect.</p>
</div>

<div id="navbar">
<a class="active" href="javascript:void(0)">Home</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)">News</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)">Contact</a>
<div class="dropdown">
<button class="dropbtn">Dropdown 
<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
</button>
<div class="dropdown-content">
<a href="#">Link 1</a>
<a href="#">Link 2</a>
<a href="#">Link 3</a>
</div>
</div> 
</div>

<div class="content">
<h3>Sticky Navigation Example</h3>
<p>The navbar will stick to the top when you reach its scroll 
position.</p>
<p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum 
definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas 
ut 
quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. 
Affert 
laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no 
molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
</div>

<script>
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
navbar.classList.add("sticky")
} else {
navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
}
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Ahmad Hassan: I have tried to modify the CSS but it doesn't seem to work. I get a second black bar where the drop down menu  is which does not stick. Most likely I'm putting the code in the wrong place. Would you be so kind to show me where the modifications must go in the CSS?

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove "overflow: hidden" from the #navbar in your css.

Example:

```
 #navbar {
   background-color: #333;
 }
```

You can learn more about CSS overflow here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow